# Derivative of $f(a)=\int_{0}^{1}\sin(t\cos(a)) \log(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Fairly simple question regarding integral dependant on parameter.

we have $f(a)=\int_{0}^{1}\sin(t\cos(a)) \log(t)dt$

We want to find $f'(a)$.

I tried to do this using Leibniz Rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f(x,y)dy\right)=\int_{y_0}^{y_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dy$$

So in our case, $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(\sin(t\cos(a)))=-t\sin(a)\cos(t\cos(a))$ note I am deriving with respect to $a$

And $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(\log(t))=0$

So overall we have using product rule for derivatives: $$f'(a)=\int_{0}^{1}-t\sin(a)\cos(t\cos(a))\log(t) dt$$

How do I integrate this monster? I know we can take the $-\sin(a)$ our of the integral as $a$ is a 'constant' since the integral is with respect to $t$, but still... $$\int_{0}^{1}t \log(t)\cos(t\cos(a))dt$$ is quite an integral to calculate...Am I in the ball park? this is first question I attempt on this subject.

Comment: I think you're supposed to stop at $\displaystyle f'(a)=\int \limits_{0}^{1}-t\sin(a)\cos(t\cos(a))\log(t) \mathrm dt$.

Comment: You don't think we are supposed to solve the integral? to get an answer where $t$ doesn't appear?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think and since $t$ is bounded, "it's not even there". You can always put it on wolfram alpha and see if you geta closed form solution. **Edit:** I put it on mathematica, it didn't even return an approximation.

Comment: I see. So I suppose it doesn't make much sense to ask a group of bachelor students to actually integrate this. Thanks Git, Appreciate your input as always.

Comment: Hint: try change of variable $z=\cos(a)$ and find derivative wrt to $z$ then use chain rule for the original derivative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are done but if you really want to integrate it...

$$f'(a)=\int_{0}^{1}-t\sin(a)\cos(t\cos(a))\log(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$$ 
I will use the following for convenience.

$$I=\int\! t\cos(bt)\log(t)  \,\mathrm{d}t$$

$$J =\int\! \cos(bt)\log(t)  \,\mathrm{d}t$$

Integration by parts:

$$I = Jt -\int\! J\,\mathrm{d}t$$

Find $J$ by parts (omitted)

$$J =\int\! \cos(bt)\log(t)  \,\mathrm{d}t = \dfrac{\log(t)\sin(bt)-\operatorname{Si}(bt)}{b}$$

Integrate $J$ by parts (omitted) and using $\int \operatorname{Si}(t) \,\mathrm{d}t = t\operatorname{Si}(t) + \cos(t)$.

$$\int J \,\mathrm{d}t = \dfrac{\operatorname{Ci}(bt)-bt\operatorname{Si}(bi)-(\log(t)+1)\cos(bt)}{b^2}$$

$$I = \left(\dfrac{bt\log(t)\sin(bt)-bt\operatorname{Si}(bt)}{b^2}\right) - \left(\dfrac{\operatorname{Ci}(bt)-bt\operatorname{Si}(bi)-(\log(t)+1)\cos(bt)}{b^2}\right)$$

$$I = \dfrac{bt\log(t)\sin(t)+(\log(t)+1)\cos(bt)-\operatorname{Ci}(bt)}{b^2}$$

Now just sub $b = \sin(a)$ and find $\sin(a)\cdot(I(0)-I(1))$.